# Text editor with word suggestion

Tags: windows, text-editor, autocomplete

I am heading a team of 15 data entry operators and we need to type a lot of pages everyday. I am looking for a Windows based software that can offer us suggestions based on the first few letters of the word.

Since typing is being on multiple machines simultaneously, I would like to consolidate the dictionary / database of words so that it can be copied on all machines and everyone can benefit. Also I would like the dictionary to get bigger over a period of time so as to aid us better.

I tried notepad ++ but (AFAIK) it does not save the suggestions. So if you open a new document, then all suggestions are lost and you start from scratch.

I hope I have made myself clear. Let me know if you need more info.

Thanx in advance
Hitesh

PS: 
Text is normal english text not sw code.
We need suggestions NOT auto correct ( ms word style)

Edit: I figured a way to provide custom dictionary by modifying the built-in ones in \plugins\API's and selecting the respective programming language.

Comment: Related on our sister-site: [How can I enable auto complete support in Notepad++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/893761/2533433) Also see: [Auto Completion - Notepad++ Wiki](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Auto_Completion). Lots of additional documents with a [Google Search on "notepad++ auto-suggest"](https://www.google.com/search?q=notepad%2B%2B+auto-suggest).